# Dynamic dropdown without external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have been trying to achieve a dynamic dropdown list on my page. The idea is that when a user changes one drop down the next one populates based on the first one.

I have been using the tutorial here: https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/ but the guide is using external text/json files. Could anyone help my understand how I would modify the code for either text/json so I do not need to use external files (i.e. i can have my options within the html file)

For text the code currently looks like:

```js
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
   $("#second-choice").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
});
```

For json the code looks like:

```js
$("#first-choice").change(function() {

 var $dropdown = $(this);

 $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {
 
  var key = $dropdown.val();
  var vals = [];
       
  switch(key) {
   case 'beverages':
    vals = data.beverages.split(",");
    break;
   case 'snacks':
    vals = data.snacks.split(",");
    break;
   case 'base':
    vals = ['Please choose from above'];
  }
  
  var $secondChoice = $("#second-choice");
  $secondChoice.empty();
  $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
   $secondChoice.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
  });

 });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to have multiple hidden drop downs, which are then displayed dependant on the value of the first:

```js
$('.first').change(function(){
  $('.option').removeClass('show');
  var val = $(this).val();
  switch(val){
    case 'Option 1':
      $('.option.one').addClass('show');
      break;
    case 'Option 2':
      $('.option.two').addClass('show');
      break;
    case 'Option 3':
      $('.option.three').addClass('show');
      break;
  }
})
```

```css
.option{
  display:none;
}
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="first">
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
   <option>Option 3</option>
</select>

<select class="option one show">
   <option>a</option>
   <option>b</option>
   <option>c</option>
</select>
<select class="option two">
   <option>d</option>
   <option>e</option>
   <option>f</option>
</select>
<select class="option three">
   <option>g</option>
   <option>h</option>
   <option>i</option>
</select>
```

or to do it in your jquery manually set the arrays

```js
$("#first-choice").change(function() {

    var $dropdown = $(this);

 var key = $dropdown.val();
                var vals = []
 var beverages = ["tea" , "coffee" , "juice"];
                var snacks = ["burger" , "sandwich" , toast"];

      
 switch(key) {
  case 'beverages':
   vals = beverages;
   break;
  case 'snacks':
   vals = snacks;
   break;
  case 'base':
   vals = ['Please choose from above'];
 }
 
 var $secondChoice = $("#second-choice");
 $secondChoice.empty();
 $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
  $secondChoice.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
 });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I would like to understand how to make the change to the existing code instead of hiding/showing divs.

Comment: You said you wanted your options within the html file, if so that's the easiest way to do it. There's really no need to dynamically populate the second drop down. But you could create a set of arrays in your javascript if you wanted to do it that way